# Enable speech to intent with picovoice SDK

Tags: react-native

I'm developing a react native application with picovice SDK to detect the  wake word and speech to intent. It will start the speech recognition once the wake word is detected. I also want to start the speech recognition with a button click without detecting the wake word. So the application need to have both of this feature.

1. Start speech to intent recognition with wake word detection.
2. Start speech to intent recognition after button click without wake word detection.

Kindly request a guide to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Picovoice has demos for both:

1. Wake Word with Speech-to-Intent https://picovoice.ai/docs/quick-start/picovoice-react-native/
2. Speech-to-Intent alone: https://picovoice.ai/docs/quick-start/rhino-react-native/

Have you tried starting with existing demos?

Comment: yes. First tried with picovoice SDK. It's working fine for speech to intent with wake word. Rhino SDK also working just for speech to intent. But Want both of this functionality in same application. 

I tried integrating both in one application. It gives unusual behavior like wake word detection is not working after processing with rhino SDK